# How to create a floating horizontal scroll bar in Angular or Ionic

Tags: angular, scrollbar

I am using Ionic 3/Anuglar 5. I have a very tall table which I would like to have a floating horizontal scroll bar across so that user does not have to go to the bottom of table.

I have come across a jquery solution below:

http://jsfiddle.net/cowboy/45rEs/show/

How would I do this in Angular or Ionic???

```
<div id="horz-scroll-wrapper" style="width: 300px; overflow: scroll">
          <div style="height: 100%;">
              <table class='sample'>
                  <tbody>
                      <tr *ngFor="let row of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26]">
                          <td >abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</td><td >ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</td><td >1234567890</td><td >0987654321</td><td >abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</td><td >ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</td><td >1234567890</td><td >0987654321</td>
                      </tr>
                  </tbody>
              </table>
          </div>
      </div>
```